# In the sequence, if a term is less than $\frac{3}{4}$ and some term after it is greater than $\frac{3}{4}$, can $\frac{3}{4}$ exists in between?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I need help verifying the solution to the following problem from the book *Reading, writing, and proving*: A closer look at mathematics. In *Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics* 2nd ed on page 10, **Problem 1.12**.

---

Shlomo Sureshot started the basketball season with a free throw shooting percentage of below **75%**. By the end of the season he brought it up to above **75%**. Must there have been a time in the season (after a free throw attempt) when his free throw percentage was exactly **75%**?

After having solved this problem and looking back at your solution, are there questions that you would like to answer? Can you answer them?

---

The following is my attempted solution:

---

The free throw percentage of a basketball player is calculated by dividing the number of free throws the player has connected by the number of free throw the player has attempted in a given time in the season after a free throw.

Consider a sequence of non-negative rational numbers which represented the player's free throw percentage after each attempted free throw from the beginning of the season to the end of the season.

$...,\frac{x}{y}, \frac{x+1}{y+1},...$ where $\frac{x}{y} < \frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{x+1}{y+1} > \frac{3}{4}$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $y\ne 0$

If there exist two consecutive terms in the sequence which the first term in the pair is less than $\frac{3}{4}$ and the term after it is more than $\frac{3}{4}$ in which the latter term's numerator is equal to the first term's numerator added by $1$ and it's denominator is equal to the first term's denominator added by $1$, then there exist a sequence which does not contain the term $\frac{3}{4}$.

However, no such $x,y$ satisfy the sequence.

If $\frac{x}{y} < \frac{3}{4}$, then for some term after it to become greater than $\frac{3}{4}$, there must exist at least two terms after $\frac{x}{y}$ which some term before the last term in the sequence is exactly $\frac{3}{4}$.

Therefore, if a basketball player starts a season with a free throw percentage less than 75%, then for the player to achieve the free throw percentage above 75% by the end of the season, there must be a moment after a free throw during the season which the player's free throw percentage is exactly 75%.

---

Reference:

Daepp, U., & Gorkin, P. (2011). *Reading, writing, and proving*: A closer look at mathematics. In *Reading, writing, and proving: A closer look at mathematics* (2nd ed., p. 10). New York: Springer.

Comment: Why would the term after $\frac xy$ be $\frac{x+1}{y+1}$???????????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich When a player successfully connected a free throw, the total number of attempted free throws, $y$, increases by $1$ and the total number of connected free throws, $x$, increases by $1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I want to show that the player's free throw percentage must be precisely 75% during the season given that the player's free throw percentage is below 75% at the beginning of the season and above 75% by the end of the season by creating the sequence representing the player' s free throw percentage and show that it is impossible for the sequence not to have the term $\frac{3}{4}$ in it the way that Jaap Scherphuis has suggested.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My reasoning is that if there is a moment in the season where the player's free throw percentage is below 75% and a moment where it is above75% without being precisely 75%, then the free throw percentage should increased from a number below 75% to the number above 75% by increasing both the total number of connected free throws and the total number of attempted free throws by $1$. However, I do not know whether my reasoning is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't follow your reasoning, which reads to me as a mere assertion that it must be true, not as a proof.

The proof is simple however given that you have already set up the inequalities that the variables $x$ and $y$ must satisfy.
$$\frac{x}y<\frac34 \implies 4x<3y$$
$$\frac{x+1}{y+1}>\frac34 \implies 4x+4>3y+3$$
Put those together to find that $4x<3y<4x+1$, which is impossible in whole numbers - there cannot be an integer $3y$ in between the successive integers $4x$ and $4x+1$.

Comment: When I have used your method of proving to show that it is not possible for the sequence to not have $\frac{3}{4}$ in it given that a player's free throw percentage is below 75% in the beginning of the season and above 75% by the end of the season, do I have to further prove that $\frac{3}{4}$ must be in the sequence by showing that $\frac{x}{y} < \frac{3}{4}$ and  $\frac{x+1}{y+1} = \frac{3}{4}$ which yields $\frac{3y -1}{4y} < \frac{3}{4}$ for some $y$ in $\mathbb{Z^+}$?

Comment: No. Once you've established that the only way for the hit rate to increase is through a successful throw, taking the score from $x$ hits out of $y$ attempts (hit rate $\frac{x}y$) to a score of $x+1$ hits out of $y+1$ attempts (hit rate $\frac{x+1}{y+1}$), then the proof I gave is sufficient. The proof is essentially proof by contradiction. It assumes the hit rate skips over 3/4, and then finds a contradiction, thereby showing that the assumption is wrong, meaning 3/4 must be visited. It does not explicitly find x and y, but that is not possible. It could be anywhere - at 30/40 or 2019/2692.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have asserted without justification that the player at some point must have had a free-throw percentage of exactly $75\%$.

It may be worth noting that at least for some free-throw percentages you can go from below to above without landing exactly.  For example a player could go from 1 for 4 ($25\%$) to 2 for 5 ($40\%$). They never hit $30\%$ exactly; they just passed over it.